# Как записать строковое значение в переменную с помощью ассемблерной вставки (masm)?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, masm32

С целочисленными переменными мы можем сделать так:

```
int a;
_asm {
  mov eax, 10;
  mov a, eax;
}
```

Вопрос: можно ли сделать так со строками и если да, то как?

Comment: Поясните что имеется в виду. Аналог `strcpy()`, записать адрес в указатель, или что-то другое?

Comment: @PinkTux Я хочу объявить строковой литерал в ассемблерном коде и с помощью манипуляций с указателями передать его в переменную `char*`.

Comment: переменную для хранения строки все таки лучше выделить в C (char [] или maloc/new и т.п.) А дельше в asm загружаете адрес строки и по указателю заносите значения или копируете

Comment: @Mike, ну так вот, у меня вопрос: как занести значение?

Comment: Объявить строковый литерал (в inline-MASM), ЕМНИП, не получится. В остальном всё точно так же, как и в коде из вопроса. *"как занести значение"* -- да так и занести, копированием нужного количества байт из одного места в другое.

Comment: А что гадать? Вы напишите функцию, содержащую нужную операцию, скомпилируйте её с ключом, заставляющим выводить ассемблерный код, и посмотрите.

Comment: Если есть указатель то mov si, указатель; mov ds:[si], al (если 1 байт) только смотрите _где_ находится ваша строка, если она в стеке то следует использовать для адресации ss:[bp]. так что для начала выделите память под переменную так, как вы предполагали, потом напишите что то типа str[0]=5; и посмотрите ассемблерный код который генерит компилятор что бы точно узнать где строка и как ее следует адресовать

Comment: Поправил код так, чтобы меня правильно поняли.

Comment: Ни на ассемблере, ни на чистом Си нельзя просто взять и записать строковой литерал в "переменную". На Си есть такие функции как `strcpy`, на ассемблере (внезапно) тоже можно использовать `strcpy`, а можно каким-нибудь циклом (например через `rep movs`/`movsd`) копировать по одному или несколько байт строку в отведенную под нее память.

Comment: Приведите пример "черновика" что вы хотите сделать на с++ с вставкой, Может вам это нужно `char c[10] ; _asm{ mov eax, c; mov cl,65; mov [eax], cl; mov [eax+1], 0;   }`. Ещё можно написать на с++, дизассемблировать, и передрать с дизассемблера в ассемблерную вставку, и переделать немного как вам нужно. Для винды `hiew.exe` поможет (само проще).